# Get status callback from a javascript async function

Tags: javascript

I'm not so skilled on JS.

I'm importing a function from an external lib

```
import { doSomething } from '@/javascript/solana.ts';
```

Into this lib execute is defined in this way..

```
export async function doSomething(...) { 
 ....
 try {
  ... 
} catch (e) {
  ...  
}
}
```

In my code I need to catch for error and for success.

I have a function that call my imported function

```
function drawImages() {
  doSomething( ... ).catch(e => {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + e.message);
  });
}
```

How can I manage the success?

Comment: Since you're not using `await`, you should be able to do your success functions inside of the `then()` block, i.e. `doSomething(...).then(() => onSuccess()).catch(e => onFailure())`. You could also add a `.finally()` on the end if you want to do always something regardless of failure or success. [Check out the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Promise#then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to handle the value returned when it is successful.

```js
function drawImages() {
  doSomething( /* ... */ ).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(e => {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + e.message);
  });
}
```